# Perl Module to get all pages of a website?

Tags: perl, scripting, module, web-crawler

Is there a module out there that can give me links to all the pages a website has??

Why I need it: I want to crawl some sites and search for tags in them, searching only on mainpage is not enough.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-SimpleLinkExtor) is a bit simple than [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-LinkExtor). You might check out my half-hearted attempt at my [webreaper tool](http://search.cpan.org/dist/webreaper) that has some of the code that you'll probably need.

Answer (score 5):

The classic way to crawl sites in Perl is with [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) which has a links method that returns a list of all the links from the page.  You can grab a page, get the links from it, and then use the follow_link() or get() method to get the linked page.

Comment: Thanks, I already know that module, but its too much(?) of an overhead to use it only for this function I guess

Answer (score 2):

You may find [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::LinkExtor) of use.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) to parse the HTML from the page.  It returns a tree of objects that you can use to grab all of the links from a page, and it can do much more, such as finding a link based on a regexp pattern you specify.  Check out HTML::Element's documentation to see more.

To find all of the links in a page:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url  = 'http://www.example.com/';
my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(get($url));

my @links = $html->look_down('_tag'   => 'a');
```

I believe LWP::Simple and HTML::TreeBuilder are both included in Ubuntu as well.